# Regex for capturing .pdf file extention and everything in front of it until a space-space

Tags: regex, ecmascript-6

So my problem is I have this very large .csv file that has these long file names contained within. I would like to just capture the file extension .pdf and everything forward of it until I reach a - . I bolded what I need to use regex to extract. I am using ECMAScript (Javascript).

I am new with regex and still working on mastery.

,CT - Cash Thang (Version 2019) - IBM SERVICES - **CMSA123456789012345.PDF** - Active - 12/20/2018 5:29:58 PM
,CT - Cash Thang (Version 2019) - IBM SERVICES - **CMSA-12345678-9012345.PDF** - Active - 12/20/2018 5:29:58 PM
,CT - Cash Thang (Version 2019) - IBM SERVICES - **C A 12345678-9012345.PDF **- Active - 12/20/2018 5:29:58 PM
,CT - Cash Thang (Version 2019) - IBM SERVICES - **C A 123456789012345.PDF** - Active - 12/20/2018 5:29:58 PM
,CT - Cash Thang (Version 2019) - IBM SERVICES - **CMSA+12345678-9 012345.PDF** - Active - 12/20/2018 5:29:58 PM

I have tried examples from all over the web. I was hoping to anchor on .PDF and somehow lookahead and capture everything until I reach the first - . (space-space)

Comment: Java or JavaScript? Those aren't the same. ECMAScript is JavaScript, not Java.

Comment: What about `(?<=- )(?:(?! - ).)*?\.PDF`  Have a look at https://regex101.com/r/ax1OC4/1

Comment: You solved it. And thank you for the regex101 reference!!